# What is AdBlock blocking on my website?

Tags: html, website, adblock, webpage, bad-blocks

While reading my [webpage](http://prohackr112.tk/r/stack-overflow-comments) I noticed that AdBlock was blocking one element. I certainly don't have any ads. Here's the entire source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Stack Overflow Comments</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.png" />

  <meta name="description" content="Handy comments to use on Stack Overflow" />
  <meta name="author" content="Ryan Klingler" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="Stack,Overflow,Ryan,comments" />

</head>
<body style="line-height: 150%; background-color: #d3d3d3">
  <h1>Handy Stack Overflow Comments</h1>

  <strong>Bad code (sarcastic)</strong>
  <input type="text" style="width:100%; font-family: monospace;" onfocus="this.select();" class="field left" value="You should look into [proper C formatting](//prohackr112.tk/pcf). Or learn how to [thoroughly obfuscate your code](//prohackr112.tk/guide/coding/proper-c-obfuscation)." readonly>

  <strong>Bad code (helpful)</strong>
  <input type="text" style="width:100%; font-family: monospace;" onfocus="this.select();" value="You should [properly format your code](//prohackr112.tk/pcf). Using proper formatting attracts people to your question and encourages them to help you." class="field left" readonly>

  <br><strong>Missing MCVE (new user)</strong>
  <input type="text" style="width:100%; font-family: monospace;" onfocus="this.select();" value="Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](/help/mcve)." class="field left" readonly>

  <strong>Missing MCVE (not-so-new user)</strong>
  <input type="text" style="width:100%; font-family: monospace;" onfocus="this.select();" class="field left" value="Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](/help/mcve)." readonly>

  <strong>Missing MCVE (no code provided)</strong>
  <input type="text" style="width:100%; font-family: monospace;" onfocus="this.select();" class="field left" value="Please post your code. But first, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](/help/mcve)." readonly>

  <strong>Complete "gimme teh codez" question<strong>
  <input type="text" style="width:100%; font-family: monospace;" onfocus="this.select();" class="field left" value="&quot;Gimme teh codez!!1&quot; - &quot;No.&quot;" readonly>

</body>
</html>
```

What is AdBlock doing?

Comment: Which element is blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to view-source:http://prohackr112.tk/r/stack-overflow-comments

At the bottom, you see

```
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php">
</script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

That is what is being blocked: http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php

To see what is blocked in Google Chrome, press <kbd>F12</kbd> and click on "ad block"

To see what is blocked in Firefox, click on the ad block icon and press "open blockable items"

Comment: Host is injecting code into your page. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268868/